# Proper way to give permissions to a program

Tags: permissions, users

At work there is a "system" (python) agent that needs to perform actions with higher level privileges (adding ip route, setup wifi profile, reading from serial devices), but also be able to launch other programs of this "system", read/write to files/local db. So far I know two options:

1. add the higher level permissions to the "default" user and launch it as normal user. "default" user is the one that the engineer logs into.
2. create a separate "test" user and add required permissions by creating new groups with those permissions and adding groups to the "test" user.

From what I gathered option 1 is not very "safe" way to do things.
Option 2 has difficulties with general file permissions and launching new terminals (X11 display problem). If I do manage to start those programs, they will be using the "test" user and all the files those programs create will not be accessible to the default user. The "system" should also be able to mostly automatically setup that user, and agent needs the ability to be started/stopped through our UI, so it will have to be launched from "default" user and require password input (or needs to be saved in the "system" files).

Is it worth the hassle to go with option 2, or should I just go with option 1? I should also note, that this "system" will be used in many computers at work, so it's not just my personal computer.

Comment: What is a "default" user? What is a "normal" user? How do you intend to "add the higher level permissions" to the "default" user? What are the "required permissions" you're thinking of adding to the "test" user? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: Also, some of the operations you mentioned (adding ip route, setup wifi profile) require root permissions. If there's only one agent that should do all of those things, how do you intend to separate the different operations to different users?

Comment: Can you not achieve what you want by simply running your "system" agent under `sudo`?

Comment: By "default" I mean the user that the engineers login to. I could add permissions to it by creating a new group (ex dialout for serial) with those permissions and add the group to the "default" user.
I am not sure that I understand the separation question. The agent should have the ability to do all the required things with one user privileges.
@Seamus Afaik we cannot run the agent with sudo, as the agent needs to be run inside a python environment and will be missing packages.

Comment: some of the operations you mentioned (adding ip route, setup wifi profile) require root permissions. So your agent will **have** to run with root privileges to able to perform them. So how can the agent run as a normal user and still perform those operations? I don't know if there's any group that supports those operations for non-root users.

Comment: This sound like a scripting/programming question and might be a better fit for Stack Overflow. See also [this question on switching user identities in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25928190/python-run-command-as-normal-user-in-a-root-script) and [this question with further clarification to the previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74735674/how-do-i-use-setuid-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

Trying to devolve permissions for OS related operations such as configuring routes would require extensive modofications to file permissions. OTOH configuration permissions for non-privileged users to access data files is something we do every day.

> give permissions to a program

The permissions a program runs with are inherited from the user whom invoked it. There are some exceptions to this but you should avoid them until you know a LOT more about Linux/Unix (specifically, setuid, MAC and capabilities).

If you were to go down the road of attempting to change permissions to allow changes to routes, you will likely compromise the security of your system and the changes will probably be reverted the next time you apply an upgrade.

These 2 different things need 2 different solutions.

First, the routes and wifi config: configure sudo as root for this. If possible, package the behaviours up into non-interactive shell scripts - this will help prevent sudo backdoors.

> to the "default" user

We don't know what "default user" means on your system.

For data access (i.e. files not maintained by your linux distribution) you need to define a model describing the classes of user whom should have different types of access then use standard groups to permit that access. Adding interactive user accounts that don't align with human beings is an anti-pattern. Add/remove groups to the users whom actually exist.

Hint: `chmod g+s $DIRNAME` will preserve the group ownership on any new files/directories created in $DIRNAME.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using `chmod g+s $DIRNAME` from @symcbean, but it only sets the group for the files and I did not find an option to set the user as well. Also iirc files were still being opened in RO mode, even though the group was the same as the logged in user.

My initial statement about running python program with `sudo` inside ENV seems to be wrong, as I was successful in doing that by providing the full path of python ENV binary. I read up on the links provided by @telcoM and performed `setegid` and `seteuid` inside the program, which allows the program to create files with the invokers permissions and also execute commands that require `root`.

The last problem I encountered was that the program was launching other programs in additional terminals, but either did it in a seemingly root-owned gnome-terminal (different profile and had a toolbar), or did not launch at all due to XAUTH problems. This was solved by using `--preserve-env` argument with `sudo`.

So the current solution for me is:

1. Launch program using `sudo --preserve-env <python_env_binary> <python_program>`
2. (inside python program) Check if being run by `sudo` and env is preserved (check if `geteuid` is 0 and $HOME environment variable is not `/root`)
3. Get invoker ID from $SUDO_UID and $SUDO_GID
4. Use invoker ID to set `setegid` and `seteuid` (GID FIRST!)

Let me know if this solution makes sense.